# Word to describe the process of continuing to communicate with an end user

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on the branding of a company and we need to come up with a single word to describe the concept of continuing to publish content to an end user over a longer period of time. We've brainstormed words like "stream" if that helps, but that particular term doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Feed, stream, updates, revise, refresh, notify

Comment: I like feed, I'll pass that back on to the other guys. The other words after stream don't really work as it's a marketing platform - users will receive ongoing content from their publisher.

Comment: citations please

Comment: Also perhaps push (verb), news (noun).